# How to get with statement working with zinnia tag

Tags: python, django, for-loop, with-statement, zinnia

I got a problem with iteration on zinnia tag outcome. Let's say that that tag returns a list of some categories, I tried to manage it in few ways:

```
{% with categories=get_plain_categories %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

or simply:

```
{% for category in get_plain_categories %}
    <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

But in both ways, it seems to not even run `get_plain_categories` tag (I made few prints in it), but when I write : `{% get_plain_categories %}`, it returns list as it's supposed to.

How should I get that working?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly `with` tag is not that powerful, you can't use it with output of other tags. You'll have to [create your own tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

As an example you can have a look at the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static). It lets you insert a path to a static file with `{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}` but you can't easily save it to a variable for later use. That's why in Django 1.5 it got a new syntax `{% static "images/hi.jpg" as myphoto %}` and this way you can later use `{{ myphoto }}`. This can't be achieved with `with`.

That said, I can't find any mentions of `get_plain_categories` in Google, which is weird.

Comment: the issue is, that i want insert into HTML every single object from returned by zinnia tag list of objects, that must be somehow possible. As far as I'm  concerned creating a tag  which will  return ready html code, isn't so "clean programming" style

Comment: @user2466146 that's why I've told you how it was done in `static`. You could create tag that will assign this list to a variable and then just use the code you've shown in the question. The only wrong thing in your code is that you can't use `with` this way. But you should create a tag that will bind this list to a name and use it like `{% my_get_plain_categories as categories %}`.

Comment: {% my_get_plain_categories as categories %}    returns: 'my_get_plain_categories' received too many positional arguments